# Solve the initial value problems for $u_t+2u_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$u_t+2u_x=0$ initial value is $u(-1,x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$
Using the characteristic method i find that $\zeta= x-2t$
so the solution will be $$u(t,x)=\frac{x-2t}{1+(x-2t)^2}$$
so therefore when i plug in the initial value of  $u(-1,x)$, i should of get  $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. So i thought the initial value was wrong, when i was talking to my teacher he told me there is a way to rewrite the solution so the initial value can satisfy. can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found the solution such that $u(0,x)=x/(1+x^2)$, but the one you want satisfies $u(-1,x)=x/(1+x^2)$. All you need is a translation in time.

Comment: i know but how do you do that. that is where i am stuck. I need a hint please, i have been at this for quite sometimes now and i am not getting anywhere

Comment: $t\mapsto t+1$.